# Pyspark UDF broadcasted variable undefined only when imported by separate script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nameerror, udf, spark-submit

Here are two minimal working example scripts that both invoke a UDF in pyspark. The UDF relies on a broadcasted dictionary, with which it maps a column to a new column. A full working example which produces the correct output is as follows:

```
# default_sparkjob.py

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def _transform_df(sc, df):    
    global mapping
    mapping = {1:'First', 2:'Second', 3:'Third'}
    mapping = sc.broadcast(mapping)

    udf_implement_map = F.udf(_implement_map, StringType())
    df = df.withColumn('Mapped', udf_implement_map('A'))
    return df

def _implement_map(column):
    return mapping.value[column]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #_____________________________________________________________________________
    sc = SparkContext()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    #_____________________________________________________________________________

    import pandas as pd
    pd_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['a','b','c']} )
    sp_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df)

    sp_df = _transform_df(sc, sp_df)
    sp_df.show()

# OUTPUT:
#+---+---+------+
#|  A|  B|Mapped|
#+---+---+------+
#|  1|  a| First|
#|  2|  b|Second|
#|  3|  c| Third|
#+---+---+------+
```

However, if in a separate script, the function is imported and used, it says that the mapping isn't defined:

```
# calling_sparkjob.py

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #_____________________________________________________________________________
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, DataFrame
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F

    sc = SparkContext(pyFiles=['default_sparkjob.py'])
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    #_____________________________________________________________________________

    from default_sparkjob import _transform_df
    import pandas as pd
    pd_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['a','b','c']} )
    sp_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df)

    sp_df = _transform_df(sc, sp_df)
    sp_df.show()

    # File "default_sparkjob.py", line 17, in _implement_map
    # return mapping.value[column]
    # NameError: global name 'mapping' is not defined
```

Can anyone please explain why this happens? This is currently a major roadblock in the real version of the code which imports many functions which rely on many udfs from external files. Is there a namespace issue I am not understanding?

Thanks very much.

Comment: try this ``def _implement_map(column):
    return globals()["mapping"].value[column]``

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thank you for your reply. That change yields: `return globals()["mapping"].value[column]
KeyError: 'mapping'` in both scripts when submitted individually.

Comment: ok, can you print all these three things before ``return``, ``print dir(), print locals(), print globals()`` and check whether ``mapping`` is there or not

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I cannot print from within a pyspark udf. Do you mean before the call to the UDF?

Comment: no you should try ``def _implement_map(column): print globals() print dir() print locals() return mapping.value[column]`` this will show global mapping

Comment: Hello i think you need to place ``_implement_map``, ``inside _transform_df`` function def

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When the function is imported from other file, the program will raise an error.

I don't know if you have a solution now, **but I find a trick solution**.

You can convert the dict variable to string, then add a new column to the dataframe with the value of F.lit(str), finally in the udf use ast.literal_eval to convert the str to dict and use it in udf.

Maybe look at the code will be more clear.

```
# default_sparkjob.py

import ast

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def _transform_df(sc, df):
    # global mapping
    mapping = {1:'First', 2:'Second', 3:'Third'}
    # mapping = sc.broadcast(mapping)
    df = df.withColumn('mapping_config', F.lit(str(mapping)))

    udf_implement_map = F.udf(_implement_map, StringType())
    df = df.withColumn('Mapped', udf_implement_map('A', 'mapping_config'))
    return df

def _implement_map(column, mapping_config):
    mapping_ = ast.literal_eval(mapping_config)
    return mapping_[column]
```

Then use your calling_sparkjob.py to get the right results.

```
+---+---+--------------------+------+
|  A|  B|      mapping_config|Mapped|
+---+---+--------------------+------+
|  1|  a|{1: 'First', 2: '...| First|
|  2|  b|{1: 'First', 2: '...|Second|
|  3|  c|{1: 'First', 2: '...| Third|
+---+---+--------------------+------+
```